# Lots of processes killed by SIGTRAP

Tags: java

Since yesterday, my Linux (**Fedora 20**) randomly kills processes for no reason at all (at least from my point of view), and the bugs reports say that all these processes are **"killed by SIGTRAP"**. It happens with evolution, gls, the weather app, Google Chrome, and so on ...

Also, when trying to run a Scala Play Framework application, I get the error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

I stuck with this, it makes my Linux partition totally unusable!

Does anyone have an idea about what causes this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that by increasing the max number of allowed processes by user to 2048 worked for me, following this : http://miyurudw.blogspot.fr/2012/06/javalangoutofmemoryerror-unable-to.html

Comment: Did this solve the `SIGTRAP` problem, or the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` problem, or both?

Comment: It seems to have solved both of these issues !

Answer (score 0):

You can look at your memory using `top` and see if you are really out of memory (e.g. because swap was not enables) or not.

If you have enough memory, this might indicate a memory corruption causing the programs to execute some bad instructions. If this persists after a reboot, you should run a memory checker to make sure you don't have permanently faulty memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I checked with `top` but I had something like 8 Go of memory free.

Also, I have a Windows partition that works well, so I don't thing memory has a problem, but I will perform a memcheck, in case it is connected.